# How to build openssl with clang(rather than gcc) on a FreeBSD machine?

Tags: freebsd, python, openssl, https, clang

I have a 64 bit FreeBSD build machine. I need to add https support in my python3 application code. For that it is advised to build/compile python with openssl support. I do not need any gcc dependency in my final executable.

So instead i am using clang to build python. But before that while building openssl I am unable to do so.

I even used "set CC clang". But still openssl is taking up gcc as the c compiler.So on running "ldd" on the final dynamic executable it is showing up libc dependency.

This link does not mention anything about FreeBSD and clang. (https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation)

Please suggest some alternative?

[EDIT]
These are the command I am executing on my `\bin\sh` shell

`set CC clang`

`./config -fPIC`

In the output I notice the following line which indicates gcc being used:

`BN_ASM =x86_64-gcc.o`

Comment: What is your shell (your `set` looks wrong to me), and which build command (`config` or `Configure`) are you using?

Comment: These are the command I am executing on my `\bin\csh` shell :
`set CC clang`
`./config -fPIC`
In the output I notice the following line which indicates gcc being used :
`BN_ASM        =x86_64-gcc.o`

Comment: Careful. You're showing your slashes going the wrong way. Clang is the default compiler on FreeBSD version 10 and later. Which version are you on?

Comment: FreeBSD python is build with SSL support by default - you should just need to install the package. And if you need something out of the ordinary, build it from [ports](https://www.freebsd.org/ports/) rather than from a source tarball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having a number of issues, summarised below. You *almost certainly* should be using a port for python as noted by @mjturner, which will use the native FreeBSD OpenSSL.

- in `csh` the syntax `set CC clang` sets two variables named `CC` and `clang` to the empty string, you want `set CC=clang`, but even that won't work (see next point)
- simply setting a variable in your `csh` shell won't affect anything else, you really want to use `setenv CC clang` (note this one doesn't use `=`). `config` is an `sh` script, so the variable must be exported to be seen.
- `libc` is *not* a dependency of `gcc`, almost everything you link dynamically will be linked against libc (on FreeBSD this is not GNU glibc). The alternative is to link *statically* which, if possible, removes the dynamic dependency by embedding the required code in the final binary.
  (When you use `gcc` there may be a `libgcc` dependency on some platforms and is used for exception handing. This is harder to avoid.)
  I would expect you will have trouble linking python statically.

If you are instead building OpenSSL and python using clang for some purpose such as distribution of binaries (assuming you have carefully read the relevant licence agreements), or have a requirement for specific software versions, this should be possible by correctly setting `CC`. I note though that the [OpenSSL port](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/security/openssl/files/) does not do this, it opts to patching the `gcc` commands out of the `Configure` script and uses the `FREEBSDCC` environment variable instead.

Other advice:

- see the OpenSSL wiki for using clang: https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Modifying_Build_Settings `clang` *is* in fact covered, but not FreeBSD specifically because all BSDs are considered effectively equivalent there.
- make sure to run `make test` after you build OpenSSL
- make sure to compile everything with the same compiler, this means `python` and everything in `lib-dynload`

Comment: Thanks a lot sir @mr.spuratic . As suggested by you and mjturner, using the FreeBSD package installed python my problem got solved. Earlier i was having core dumped issue for the executable. That is also resolved now.